# Gödel numbering for sequences Using the Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: logic, incompleteness, chinese-remainder-theorem

I looked into some YouTube videos and got a simple idea about **Gödel numbering** and **Chinese remainder theorem** separately... But can't see how to use them as one. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering_for_sequences#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_theorem) giving a way or may be it's an explanation... any way I didn't get what's it's saying.

If anybody can give a brief explanation about **Gödel numbering** and **Chinese remainder theorem** and how to use them together, it would be really helpful.

Cheers!!!

Comment: There can't be a **brief** explanation, but you can read Peter Smith's free online book "Godel without tears" if you're interested in the incompleteness theorems. Even his book does not include all technical details because including them would make it much longer, but the key ideas are explained in sufficient detail.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing two *different* methods for representing a finite sequence of natural numbers, which are often explained together because both originated in Gödel's 1931 paper that proved the Incompleteness Theorem:

**Gödel numbering** represents a sequence $(a_1,a_2,a_n,\ldots,a_n)$ by the *single number*
$$ 2^{a_1}\cdot 3^{a_2}\cdot 5^{a_3}\cdot 7^{a_4} \cdots p_n^{a_n} $$
**Gödel's β trick** represents the sequence using *two* numbers $k$ and $m$, such that
$$ a_n = k \bmod (m\cdot n+1) $$
The Chinese Remainder Theorem is used to prove that every finite sequence can be represented in this way, if we can find a sufficiently long arithmetic sequence of sufficiently large coprime integers. (Which we can, for example by choosing $m$ as the factorial of the maximum of the largest element and the number of elements of the sequence).

The reason to have two methods of achieving apparently the same result is that they have different advantages that are neccessary for different purposes.

- Gödel numbers represent a sequence by a *single* number, which is technically convenient.
- Gödel numbers are *unique*, that is, every sequence has just one Gödel number. So you can check whether two sequences are the same simply by comparing their Gödel numbers.
- Gödel numbers are somewhat involved to construct and take apart, but not more involved than what can be done with primitive recursive functions.
- On the other hand, a sequence encoded by the β trick is *extremely easy to decode*, with much simpler tools than primitive recursion. It is therefore useful when we're trying to show what can be done using those simpler tools.

It is not particularly simple to *encode* a given sequence with the β trick, but as it turns out, we do not actually need to do that -- the trick is almost exclusively used in a context where what we want to show is that the claim "there exists a sequence such that etc etc etc" can be *expressed* in a particular formal system -- and so all we need is to quantify simultaneously over all $k$ and $m$.